# Best practices for protecting properties in Entity Object (Entity Framework 6.0)

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, oop

In my entity object I have 2 properties that I don’t want to be public (they represent the same option, but must be used on behalf of a setting). A way to implement what I want could be as follows:

```
private string Path1 { get; set; }
private string Path2 { get; set; }

public string GetThePath()
{
    if([expression])
        return Path1;
    return Path2;
}
```

But I am not sure that it is best practices to write a method in an Entity Object.
What will be best practices for the example above?

Comment: There is no problem with your approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is depend on which architecture you have used or you want used it.
We have a good pratice with keeping the POCO Entities without any functionally(behaviours). Just as a data container (only public properties).

I saw some open source projects which they are mixing the validation within the POCO's and I saw other projects which they have added some behaviours to the entities.

If you really want to keep your entity without any behaviour:

- You can use a Decorator pattern to attach additional responsibilities to an entity dynamically
- You can handle the data handling issues in the bussines logic layer.